# detect when uiscrollview frame touch the main screen bounds

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scroll, geometry

how can i detect when a `UIScrollView`frame intersect with the main screen (when scrolling) in both direction up and down? i was trying to do it like so :

```
- (void)detectScreenBoundsIntersect{
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect([myScrollView frame], [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds])) {
        NSLog(@"COLLISION");
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work! Thanks.

Comment: a `UIScrollView` object doesn't move while scrolling. Do you want to know if the contents have reached the edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adopt the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol in the view controller and set the scroll view's delegate to the controller. Adopt the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method.

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if ( [self hasReachedAVerticalEdge] ) {
        NSLog(@"At World's End");
    }
}

- (BOOL) hasReachedAVerticalEdge {
    CGPoint offset = myScrollView.contentOffSet;
    CGSize contentSize = myScrollView.contentSize;
    CGFloat height = myScrollView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat width  = myScrollView.frame.size.width;

    if ( offset.y == 0 || 
         (offset.y + height) == contentSize.height ) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

**Checking if an image view falls in the visible portion of the scroll view.**

```
- (BOOL)isContentFrameVisible:(CGRect)aFrame {
    CGRect visibleRect = CGRectZero;
    visibleRect.origin = myScrollView.offset;
    visibleRect.size = myScrollView.frame.size;

    if ( CGRectIntersectsRect(visibleRect, aFrame) ) {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this doesn't seem to work in my case!!

Comment: Then I didn't get what you were looking for. Can you explain it a bit.

Comment: i call this method inside the method : `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event`with just an `NSLog` call so i can see and i got a log before the scrollview reach the edge of the screen.

Comment: the viewController of my view that contain this scrollview

Comment: That method is probably not getting called. `UIScrollView` object is usurping the touches. I will update my answer with the alternative approach.

Comment: Thanks, so where can i call this method to handle when the edge is reached? cause i want to continue scrolling : my main problem is that i have i huge gallery of images (300 images downloaded from flikr) and each image has a title and i want to be able to continu scrolling until i reach a title of an image that i want and then display it(this save a lot of bandwidth)! it seems veru difficult! any idea will be great :)

Comment: Thanks for the code, but doesn't work! when i begin touch the scrollView and before reaching any edge i got  a lot of logs (At world's end)

Comment: Yes. That's because I am checking for horizontal edges too.

Comment: Updated only to deal with vertical edges.

Comment: Ok i know why this doesn't work, i got just one log at the end of the whole images (300), it seems that your code handle all content not just one image at a time. Thanks if you have an idea.

Comment: ooh ok. So now I get your problem. You have laid out multiple image views one after the other. You want to know when we are moving to next image view?

Comment: Yes this is what i want, so i can handle continu scrolling without loading the images i'm not intreseted in(i skeep them to save bandwidth). Thanks.

Comment: Use `UITableView`. You won't need to load more than necessary.

Comment: I don't understand i have a code with UIScrollView and it work fine but this point is very hard to figure out.

Comment: Oops! I apologize for that suggestion. I see why. I have added a code which will tell you if a frame is on screen or not.

Comment: Thanks and what is aFrame in my case? The whole screen?

Comment: No. It is for the image view. I assumed it was a scroll view containing image views. Is it not?